# Is there a way to reduce conditions to loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I want to be able to reduce a line of code such that it can handle dynamic list lengths

```
signals = ['a', 'b', 'c']

num = df[(df[signals[x]] == True for x in len(signals))].shape[0]

num = df[(df['a'] == True) & (df['b'] == True) & (df['c'] == True)].shape[0]
```

The second definition for num works, but I would like to be able to achieve it in a similar way as the first definition. This is because my signals list varies in length and hence the number of conditions change and cant hardcode it.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? Also, why do you use `== True`?

Comment: @AMC I find that since data are messy it's not uncommon to have Boolean *-ish* columns that are True/False/np.NaN, where NaN indicates that the condition couldn't be determined (imagine like < 18 years old, but for some people you are missing birthday). So the `==True` is necessary (or perhaps at least `.fillna(False)`)

Comment: @dreadblenks is this question still open?

Comment: @Kenan, your answer works well thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your looking for rows that are all true

`df[df.all(1)]`

or

`df[df[signals].all(1)]`